# How to center the caption in onecolumn space?

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, captions, two-column, ieeetran

I used the commands `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn` to have some images in one column, but now the images' captions are not centered. How can I solve this problem?

My code is like below:

```
\one column

\begin{figure}[p]

\centering

....

\caption{...}

\label{fig:...}

\end{figure}

\twocolumn
```

**Addendum**: A full MWE is:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}     
\usepackage{times,amsmath,epsfig,amssymb,graphicx,amsfonts,pxfonts,txfonts,float‌​} 
\usepackage{subfigure,ifpdf,cite} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{figure*}[p] 
\centering \subfigure[] 
{\label{fig:Original}
   \includegraphics[width=70mm]{Lena.pdf}}% 
\label{fig:image} 
\end{figure*} 
\nocite{*} 
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} 
\bibliography{meee} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: To put an image in one column format while rest of the document is in two column, you can use the environment `figure*`.

Comment: I don't know how to use the environment you said. I actually used the figure environment(\begin{figure}).

Comment: In a two column document, simply use `\begin{figure*}....\end{figure*}`.

Comment: Thank you, I write as you said, but my problem is not solved yet. I mean the caption is not centered yet!

Comment: @Mohammad: Is the caption longer than the width of the text block? By default, LaTeX will centre the caption *only* if its less than the width of the text block, and set it in paragraph mode/style otherwise. This can be changed though.

Comment: @mohammed -- as always, we need a minimum example; the figure* stuff works for everyone else, so perhaps there is something about your document that you've not told us yet.  http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl may help you to create one of these things

Comment: my code is like below:   

\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}  


\usepackage{times,amsmath,epsfig,amssymb,graphicx,amsfonts,pxfonts,txfonts,float}  
\usepackage{subfigure}  
\usepackage{psfrag}  
\usepackage{ifpdf}  
\usepackage{cite}  

\begin{document}  

\begin{figure*}[p]  
\centering  
\subfigure[]  
{\label{fig:Original}\includegraphics[width=70mm]{Lena.pdf}}%  
\label{fig:image}  
\end{figure*}  



\nocite{*}  
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}  
\bibliography{meee}  

\end{document}

Comment: @ Werner: I changed the caption length, but the problem is the same.

Comment: @Mohammad: I've taken the liberty of copying your MWE to the main part of the question, where it can be formatted for visual intelligibility.

Comment: Dear @Mico I didn't understand you! Should I do something?

Comment: @Mohammad - sorry if I wasn't clear: What I did was to copy and paste your MWE code, given in an earlier comment, back into the main body of the question. That way, it can be arranged (by adding suitable line breaks and indentation amounts) to make it reasonable easy to read.

Comment: Are you preparing a paper for a journal? If this is so, and the journal request you to use the `IEEEtran` class with the `journal` class option, then captions for figures won't be centered by design, and I suggest you to leave them as they are. If you're not forced to use the `journal` option for `IEEEtran`, then simply load the class with the `conference` option (by deafult, one-line figure captions will now be centered): `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}`.

Answer (score 6):

If you are preparing a paper for a journal and the journal requests you to use the `IEEEtran` class with the `journal` class option, then captions for figures won't be centered by design, and I suggest you to leave them as they are. If you're not forced to use the `journal` option for `IEEEtran`, then simply load the class with the `conference` option (by deafult, one-line figure captions will now be centered):

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
```